# Python YAML parsing raising KeyError

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am trying to build an audit report of which users will have access to which topics in our kafka environment. I wrote a piece of python code that does this, but for some reason it stopped working, and I have no idea why.

I have the following code:

```
import yaml
import glob

yaml_file_names = glob.glob('/tmp/kafka-topics/topics/*.yaml')
file1 = open("Access_Audit_Report_testenv.txt", "w")
file1.close()
for each_yaml_file in yaml_file_names:
    with open(each_yaml_file) as f:
        document = yaml.safe_load(f)
        current_context = document["context"]
        for each_project in document['projects']:
            file1 = open("Access_Audit_Report_testenv.txt", "a")
            for each_topic in each_project['topics']:
                topic_name = '.'.join([current_context, each_project['name'], each_topic['name']])
                file1.write(topic_name+"\n")
                file1.write('Consumers:\n')


                for each_entry in each_topic['consumers']:
                    file1.write(str(each_entry)+"\n")

                file1.write(''+"\n")
                file1.write('Producers:\n')

                for each_entry in each_topic['producers']:
                    file1.write(str(each_entry)+"\n")

                file1.write(''+"\n")
file1.close()
```

A typical yaml file in the above-mentioned location looks like this:

```
---
context: "building_administration"
projects:
  - name: "school"
    topics:
      - name: "publish"
        plan: "default"
        consumers:
          - principal: "User:consumer_planning_test"
        producers:
          - principal: "User:producer_maintenance_test"

  - name: "iot"
    topics:
      - name: "metrics.publish"
        plan: "default"
        consumers:
          - principal: "User:consumer_maintenance_test"
          - principal: "User:consumer_planning_test"
          
        producers:
          - principal: "User:producer_planner_test"
...
```

The desired output should look something like this:

```
building_administration.school.publish
Consumers:
{'principal': 'User:consumer_planning_test'}

Producers:
{'principal': 'User:producer_maintenance_test'}

iot.metrics.publish
Consumers:
{'principal': 'User:consumer_maintenance_test'}
{'principal': 'User:consumer_planning_test'}

Producers:
{'principal': 'User:producer_planner_test'}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/kafka-audit-builder/build-audit-testenv.py", line 13, in <module>
    for each_topic in each_project['topics']:
KeyError: 'topics'
```

So I understand what a KeyError is, I just don't understand why I am seeing it? Especially since this code had been working before. Any ideas or help will really be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Could there be any other yaml files present under the directory`/tmp/kafka-topics/topics/` that has a different template?

Comment: @franklinsijo you are a genius. Thank you. Yes, there is one file that breaks this template. 

---
context: []
projects:
  - name: []
    internal_connect_test:
      - principal: "User:connect_test" 

Is there a way to exclude this file? Or should I try some other logic to future-proof it?

Comment: It is always good to check the existence of a key and then access it

Comment: @franklinsijo are you thinking along the lines of Try/Except?

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, the error message is clear. Check ```'topics' in each_project```.

Comment: @BashNewbie More like `if 'key' in dict:` check

Comment: Thank you @franklinsijo. I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @franklinsijo in the comments, I was able to solve my problem by adapting my code to the following:

```
import yaml
import glob

# yaml_file_names = glob.glob('/builds/devops1/kafka-topics/topics/*.yaml')
yaml_file_names = glob.glob('/tmp/kafka-topics/topics/*.yaml')
file1 = open("Access_Audit_Report_testenv.txt", "w")
file1.close()
for each_yaml_file in yaml_file_names:
    with open(each_yaml_file) as f:
        document = yaml.safe_load(f)
        current_context = document["context"]
        print('###################')
        print(current_context)
        for each_project in document['projects']:
            file1 = open("Access_Audit_Report_testenv.txt", "a")
            if 'topics' in each_project:
                for each_topic in each_project['topics']:
                    topic_name = '.'.join([current_context, each_project['name'], each_topic['name']])
                    print(topic_name)
                    file1.write(topic_name+"\n")
                    file1.write('Consumers:\n')

                    if 'consumers' in each_topic:
                        for each_entry in each_topic['consumers']:
                            file1.write(str(each_entry)+"\n")
                            print('Consumer:', each_entry)

                    file1.write('Producers:\n')

                    if 'producers' in each_topic:
                        for each_entry in each_topic['producers']:
                            file1.write(str(each_entry)+"\n")
                            print('Producer:', each_entry)
                    file1.write(''+"\n")
            else:
                continue
file1.close()
```